# what is the orientation given in the 3d header

Tags: 3d-view, transform-orientation

[image]

What is the orienation dropdown in the 3D header? What orientation does it talk about? I understand the orientation of the 3D manipulator which is to the right of the highlighted dropdown above, but I don't understand what the highlighted dropdown orientation is for. I'm using 2.82a and a white theme(just not to get confused).

Comment: Hello :). Those are transform orientations. Blender manual page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html

Comment: I read the doc, but I couldn't find the difference between that orientation and the orientation for the transformation manipulators

Comment: This is to set different orientation for *Move*, *Rotate* and *Scale tool*. So you don't have to change it all the time :). When set to *Default*, it follows the main transform orientation.